# How come Canadian Police Information Checks do not show arrests, only convictions?

Tags: criminal-law, canada, police, criminal-record

I was wondering if there was a way to find out what a U.S. border official will see on your record. A police information check in Canada seems to only show your conviction, no section on it that shows arrests..

A u.s. border official will be able to see your arrests, if I am right from what I researched...so..

I am wondering why the police information check does not show arrests, and, if there is a way to see it (vulnerable sector check? probably won't show either and maybe hard to obtain).  Maybe through the freedom of information act?

Comment: Presumably it doesn't show arrests because one doesn't have an opportunity to defend oneself against the charge before being arrested.

Comment: There is a presumption of innocence.    What evidence you have a border official can see  arrests?

Comment: Paparazzi and phoog, here is a quote "if you have an arrest record...".."this information will be on your criminal record and the U.S. Customs and Border Protection will have access to this information"
The USA does not presume innocence they presume guilty until proven innocent, due to terrorism issues...everybody is guilty until proven innocent. I know it sounds backwards ... but..Quote is from here: http://www.ezbordercrossing.com/the-inspection-experience/prior-criminal-offenses/crimes-that-will-make-you-inadmissible-to-the-u-s/

Comment: Wait what? I'm confused. I thought that a police check included things such as arrests or charged (even if they were dropped). At least in Ontario, there's been a whole bunch of issues with that and the Human Rights Code. The [Toronto Star put it excellently:](https://www.thestar.com/news/world/2014/06/08/star_investigation_ontario_human_rights_commission_police_records_nonconviction_records_canadian_civil_liberties_association.html)

Comment: *Commit a crime, get convicted and later secure a pardon and you are protected from workplace discrimination under Ontario’s Human Rights Code. But find yourself the subject of unproven allegations, withdrawn charges or secret police surveillance — or even make a mental health emergency call to 911 — and the routine release of that information in background police checks could undermine your career aspirations with little recourse.*